# How to run a diverse campaign without a magic user

Tags: campaign-development, party, starfinder

So right now the party I'm going to GM for wants to be 3 Soldiers (vesk, orc, android; sniper, ?, armor storm) and 1 operative (vesk; ghost). No one wants to be a caster. They're pretty deadset on their character choices. As you can imagine, I have a few concerns:

1. How to deal with story elements that have mysticism checks or would normally be dealt with by 0-level spells (away from settlements where casters can be easily hired to cast spells as a service)?
2. How to deal with encounters with, for example, incorporeal enemies?
3. Healing economy

I still want the campaign to have a variety of magical components while still keeping things fun for an anything-but-magic-focused party.

Comment: I would probably rewrite the question so it's not quite as broad.  "How to run a diverse campaign without a magic user" is much less broad, and will draw more valid answers.

Comment: Are your players coordinating their character choices to create a party? Or did each create a character Independantly without interparty discussion?

Comment: They're coordinating

Comment: Let them play through the campaign as is and let them deal with the potential  issues you brought up as best as they can. Maybe one or more will decide to multi-class.